# GDAL offline load of WMS

Tags: gdal, wms

I'm loading a WMS map using gdal.

Online access works fine, including cache. The cache looks fine, I can see the files and open the images.

When I try to load the same WMS in offline mode it works, but only if I use the same coordinates.

My issue is to open the map in offline mode for different coordinates that **overlaps** with the cached area. (It's ok if the area outside my cache would be black)

Sample Xml for the request as described in the [gdal doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html), the problem can be reproduced changing `OfflineMode` to `true` and changing the coordinates:

```xml
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="WMS">
        <Version>1.1.1</Version>
        <ServerUrl>https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?</ServerUrl>
        <Layers>OSM-WMS</Layers>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <SizeX>500</SizeX>
        <SizeY>500</SizeY>
        <UpperLeftX>9.892920</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>50.626900</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>13.978200</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>47.082800</LowerRightY>
    </DataWindow>
    <Cache>
        <Path>./gdalwmscache</Path>
        <Depth>2</Depth>
        <Extension>.jpg</Extension>
    </Cache>
    <OfflineMode>false</OfflineMode>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Comment: Please tell what happens. Does GDAL throw some error or what? If you need WMS data for offline use then why not to use some true file format like GeoPackage raster as a storage?

Comment: No error, just a black image. I'm looking into other options but I was expecting that `OfflineMode` could give something.

Comment: see also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149094/gdal-offline-load-of-wms](same question on stackoverflow)